# logLevel option not working with liquibase 3.8.0

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to use liquibase 3.8.0 on my existing db2 database. 
I have 2 schema on my database, generateChangeLog works fine for one of my schema but the command failled for the second one. 
I wan't to add --logLevel option to understand why it's not working. 
Version: 
- liquibase: 3.8.0
- java: 1.8.0_221
My VM: 
- RedHat RHEL 5.4 x86_64

I try to launch this commande line:

```
./liquibase --logLevel=debug --driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver --classpath=/opt/db2/9.7.2/java/db2jcc4.jar --changeLogFile=/tmp/db.changelog.xml --url="jdbc:db2://00.00.000.000:50001/base" --username=USER --password=PASSWORD generateChangeLog
```

I also try:

```
./liquibase --logLevel=debug --logFile=/tmp/res.log --driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver --classpath=/opt/db2/9.7.2/java/db2jcc4.jar --changeLogFile=/tmp/db.changelog.xml --url="jdbc:db2://00.00.000.000:50001/base" --username=USER --password=PASSWORD generateChangeLog
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug was fixed in Liquibase 3.8.1, released Nov 6, 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Liquibase 3.8.0, So I downgraded the liquibase core version to 3.5.5, it will resolve the issue.